# Weird JavaScript Event

Tags: javascript, html, logic

I have two methods for changing a bpm, both work basically the same way, they just take in input two separate ways. One of the function works, and the other one semi-works.

If you select method 1, and then chose 3 beats, it will switch immediately back to 4 beats. However, if you use method 2 and select 3 beats, it will stay on 3 beats.

If someone could explain this behavior, that'd be awesome!

```js
/*
** Augie Luebbers & Toni Rigolosi
**          Group 15
*/

//Take the button in our html and store it as a variable.
var runButton = document.getElementById('run-button');
//Create an event listener for the aforementioned button.
runButton.addEventListener('click', doWork, false);

/* 
** For some reason when we created this second event
** beacuse without it, it was returning null value 
** because it executed before the DOM fully loaded.
** More info: http://goo.gl/uUROPz , http://goo.gl/0Z1HdJ   <-- Stack Overflow links
*/

window.onload=function()
{
    /*
    ** After  investing about 4 hours into the extra credit we realised
    ** that the method used to change between beats 3 and 4 was specific
    ** originally we had used a method of finding the value of an input field with the type number
    ** as we had so much time devoted, we didn't want to straight out remove it
    ** so we incorporated both and a method of switching between them
    */
    var changeMethodButton = document.getElementById('changemethod-button');
    changeMethodButton.addEventListener('click', changeBeatMenu, false);
};

function changeBeatMenu ()
{
    //Clear the selection methods
        document.getElementById('selectionMain').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
        document.getElementById('changebeat-button1').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
        document.getElementById('beats').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
        document.getElementById('changebeat-button2').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
    
    //make a variable with the value of the first radio button. 
    //We only need one because there are only two options and we are using an 'if else statement'
    var radio = document.getElementById("beat-method-1").checked;
    if (radio)
    {
        //Set the selection method to visible
        document.getElementById('selectionMain').setAttribute("class", "visible");
        document.getElementById('changebeat-button1').setAttribute("class", "visible");
        
        //create an event for the new button for the selection method
        var changeBeatButton1 = document.getElementById('changebeat-button1');
        changeBeatButton1.addEventListener('click', changeBeat1, false);
    } else {
        //set the number method to visible
        document.getElementById('beats').setAttribute("class", "visible");
        document.getElementById('changebeat-button2').setAttribute("class", "visible");
        
        //create an event for the new button for the number method
        var changeBeatButton2 = document.getElementById('changebeat-button2');
        changeBeatButton2.addEventListener('click', changeBeat2, false);
    }
}

function changeBeat1 ()
{
    //creates an object holding the selection input field
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("selectionMain");
    //creates a variable with the selected item in the field
    var dropDownValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
    
    //as we are changing between 3 and 4, we test to see if it equal 3
    if (dropDownValue == 3) 
    {
        //if it does, make the fourth element hidden
        document.getElementById('beat-4').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
    } else {
        //but if it's not 3, it's 4 so...
        //we put the fourth element back to it's default state which also happens to be visible
        document.getElementById('beat-4').setAttribute("class", "beat inactive");
    }
}

//Does the same thing as the above function..
//but it uses a number input field instead of a selection input field
function changeBeat2 ()
{
    var beats = document.getElementById('beats');
    beatsInteger = beats.value;
    
    if (beatsInteger == 3) 
    {
        document.getElementById('beat-4').setAttribute("class", "hidden");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('beat-4').setAttribute("class", "beat inactive");
    }
    

}

//Create a timer based on input
function doWork ()
{
    var timer = calcMs();
    setInterval(function(){ oscillate(); }, timer);
}

//Calculate beats per millisecond
function calcMs ()
{
    var bpm = document.getElementById('bpm');
    var Ms = (60000/bpm.value);
    return Ms;
}

//Oscillate the divs between 1 and 4.
var buffer = 0;
var beatsInteger = 4;
function oscillate ()
{
    
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= beatsInteger; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById('beat-' + i).setAttribute("class", "beat inactive");
        }

        var myBeat = buffer % beatsInteger + 1;
    
        document.getElementById('beat-' + myBeat).setAttribute("class", "beat active");
    
        buffer++;
}
```

```css
/*
** Augie Luebbers & Toni Rigolosi
**          Group 15
*/

#header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.beat {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #FFD1DC;;
  border : 3px solid #FF0000;
}

.hidden {
visibility: hidden;
display: none;
}

.visible {
visibility: visible;
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!--
--
-- Augie Luebbers & Toni Rigolosi
--          Group 15
-- 
-->
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lab 3: Metronome</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Project 3">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/metro.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="header">
      <h3>Metronome</h3>
      <label for="bpm">BPM</label>
      <input type="text" name="bpm" id="bpm" placeholder="enter bpm"/>
      <button name="run-button" id="run-button">Start</button>
        <br>
      <label for="selection">SELECTION</label>
      <input type="radio" name="beat-method" value="method-1"  id="beat-method-1"> Method 1
      <input type="radio" name="beat-method" value="method-2" id="beat-method-2"> Method 2
      <button name="changemethod-button" id="changemethod-button">Submit</button>
        <br>
      <select id="selectionMain" class="hidden">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <button name="changebeat-button1" id="changebeat-button1" class="hidden">Change Beat</button>
      <!-- or -->
      <label for="beats" class="hidden">BEATS</label>
      <input type="number" name="beat" id="beats" min="3" max="4" step="1" value="4" class="hidden">
      <button name="changebeat-button2" id="changebeat-button2" class="hidden">Change Beat</button>
    </section>
    <div id="beat-1" class="beat inactive">One</div>
    <div id="beat-2" class="beat inactive">Two</div>
    <div id="beat-3" class="beat inactive">Three</div>
    <div id="beat-4" class="beat inactive">Four</div>
    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the selection changing.

Comment: Every time the user changes the selection method, you add another event listener to the Change Beat buttons. So when the user clicks on Change Beat, the method runs multiple times. But I don't see how that could cause the problem you describe.